# TCP connection to my host's public IP address using Linux netcat

Tags: linux, port, port-forwarding, netcat

I need to make a TCP connection to my machine through an application that needs only the public IP address and port to connect.

I have been able to do it in Windows, but I need to do it in Linux also.

I have used the `nc` command to open the port I want, and I have been able to connect to it with the command `nc localhost port`.

But I want to test it with the public IP instead of localhost. I have also tried to connect with telnet without success.

I have done port forwarding from my router and if I got this well, the inbound connections to the public IP:port are redirected to my LAN IP:port right?

The outpout of `nc 'my public ip' port` says *connection refused*.

My firewall is off.

Any ideas? How can I test it?

Answer (score 0):

On your linux do a `nc -l 1234` to listen on port 1234. Your router must forward that port to your box. See the manpage for `nc` for the client/server section.